# How can I make my excel-vba macro click a button?

Tags: vba, excel, printing

**Here is the situation:** 
I have several buttons in different worksheets (but in same workbook) and the only thing those buttons do is print the worksheet. So imagine 6 different worksheets that all have a print button that quickly selects the relevant information and sends it to the printer.

**Here is what I want to accomplish:**
I now want to have a single button that will effectively click on all of the six buttons at the same time. So instead of clicking on the six buttons to send every indivudual worksheet to the printer, I would click one button and all of the worksheets would be sent to the printer

**I would thus need help with creating a macro that essentially clicks on other macro-buttons which is what I am struggling with.**

Thank you for your help.
[My situation in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQRp2.jpg)

Comment: You just call each of the click subroutines in your main event.

Answer (score 2):

Call each subroutine from your main subroutine. Something like this as an example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  MsgBox "Button 1"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  MsgBox "Button 2"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
  MsgBox "Button 3"
End Sub

Private Sub Main()
  CommandButton1_Click
  CommandButton2_Click
  CommandButton3_Click
End Sub
```